# circuit component could be a security threat?

Tags: security

I've a question, 
If exist some extra component on a electronic circuit, Is it a security thread? for example in a VGA card, If exist a component except its standard component on it, Is it a security threat?
Is there any paper about this? I've searched the web, but up to now, couldn't find a proper paper.
Thanks

Comment: This looks like a question for Security SE, not stackoverflow.

Comment: It could be, obviously... depends on what you mean. Do you have any concrete examples or more detailed info? Is this something you've actually seen, and if so, in what situation? Although highly unlikely, it's not entirely unthinkable that someone has been able to sneak in an extra component that steals data from your computer and sends it out to a third party.

Comment: Thanks @Kjartan . Really. I didn't see it by myself,I should research about it, because of my thesis and it's issue of my thesis : "hardware security evaluation". I found some counterfeit defect papers. but about existence of extra component for espionage, nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about programming at all, let alone a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been some new coverage of examples of something similar being done with routers, such as [this article from the guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/may/12/glenn-greenwald-nsa-tampers-us-internet-routers-snowden):

> The NSA routinely receives – or intercepts – routers, servers and other computer network devices being exported from the US before they are delivered to the international customers. The agency then implants backdoor surveillance tools, repackages the devices with a factory seal and sends them on. 
>   (...)
>   Eventually, the implanted device connects back to the NSA.
>   (...)
>   It is quite possible that Chinese firms are implanting surveillance mechanisms in their network devices. But the US is certainly doing the same.

There's a little more (and also some blury images purported to be of NSA operatives in action) in [this techradar article](http://www.techradar.com/news/networking/routers-storage/photos-reveal-nsa-tampered-with-cisco-router-prior-to-export-1249191).

These deal with bigger components though - as in whole routers getting tampered with - not just a small circuit or card, so this may not be exactly what you are looking for(?). Still it gives an indication of not just what is possible, but also of some of the motivations that exist; it's a pretty brazen act for the NSA (or anyone else) to intercept and tamper with hardware in this way, yet it *does* happen.

Comment: Thanks @Kjartan. papers, that you linked to me was helpful.